# How to groupby multiple columns with count unique value in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame `df_data`:

```
CustID    MatchID    LocationID   isMajor  #Major is 1 and Minor is 0
  1        11111       324         0  
  1        11111       324         0
  1        11111       324         0
  1        22222       490         0
  1        33333       675         1
  2        44444       888         0
```

I have a function and parameter like this:

```
def compute_something(list_minor = None, list_major = None):
   return pass
```

**Explain Parameters**: with `CustID = 1` the parameters should be `list_minor = [3,1]` (position is not important), `list_major = [1]` because with `LocationID = 324` he get 3 times and `LocationID = 490` he get 1 time (`324,490` gets `isMajor = 0` so it should be into 1 `list`). Similiar, `CustID2` have parameters `list_minor = [1]` and `list_major = []` (if he don't have data major/minor, I should be pass `[]`.

This is my program:

```
data = [
    [1, 11111, 324, 0],
    [1, 11111, 324, 0],
    [1, 11111, 324, 0],
    [1, 22222, 490, 0],
    [1, 33333, 675, 1],
    [2, 44444, 888, 0]
]
df_data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['CustID','MatchID','LocationID','IsMajor'])
df_parameter = DataFrame()

df_parameter['parameters'] = df.groupby(['CustID','MatchID','IsMajor'])['LeagueID'].nunique()
```

But results of `df_parameter['parameters']` is wrong:

```
                                    parameters
 CustID     MatchID    IsMajor
   1         11111        0             1   #should be 3
             22222        0             1
             33333        1             1
   2         44444        0             1
```

Can I get the parameters I explained above with groupby and pass them to the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
(df.groupby(['CustID','isMajor', 'MatchID']).size()
   .groupby(level=[0,1]).agg(set)
   .unstack('isMajor')
)
```

Output:

```
isMajor       0    1
CustID              
1        {1, 3}  {1}
2           {1}  NaN
```

---

**Update** Try this one groupby:

```
(df.groupby(['CustID','isMajor'])['MatchID']
   .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().agg(list))
   .unstack('isMajor')
)
```

Also, groupby with two keys can be slow. In that case, you can just concatenate the keys and groupby on that:

```
keys = df['CustID'].astype(str) + '_' + df['isMajor'].astype(str)

(df.groupby(keys)['MatchID']
   .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().agg(list))
)
```

Comment: hi @Quang Hoang, your result is different from what I expected result. With `CustID = 1` I want to get value of `isMajor = 0` is `[3,1]` but in your solution I just get `3`.

Comment: I forgot each column with each position in `groupby` will get a different result!!!

Comment: Hi @Quang Hoang, Can I ask you something? I saw you used to `unstack` to change index and column so I check your Output with `info()` and I see column names are `0` and `1`, but when I get data from the column name, I get a KeyError, It's so weird.

Comment: Depending of `isMajor` type. They might be `'0'` not `0`.

Comment: I'm testing your solution in ~ 20 mil data and it very slowly, I'm waiting for 20p and it has not completed. Do you have other ideas?

Comment: It is slow because `agg(set)` is not vectorized. I don't think there's a way to overcome this due to your specific requirement. Replace `set` with `list` might help, but you might get duplicates, e.g. `[1,1,3]` instead of `{1,3}`.

Comment: One other way is to combine `CustID` and `isMajor` into one single column, then `groupby` that column.

Comment: I replaced `set` to `list`, actually `agg(list)` to get right my expected results (I want to get duplicates value). I'm testing with `agg(list)`

Comment: @ToanNguyenPhuoc see updated answer. Here you only groupby once and it should be much faster.