# Improve performance groupby pandas with bincount numpy in python

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy

I have DataFrame like this:

```
data = [
    [1, 11111, 324, 0],
    [1, 11111, 324, 0],
    [1, 11111, 324, 0],
    [1, 22222, 490, 0],
    [1, 33333, 675, 1],
    [2, 44444, 888, 0]
]

df_data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['CustID','MatchID','LocationID','IsMajor'])

# These are my results I want to return
df_result = pd.DataFrame()
df_result = (df.groupby(['CustID','IsMajor'])['MatchID']
               .agg(lambda x: list(x.value_counts()))
               .unstack('IsMajor',fill_value = []))
```

Result of `df_result`:

```
IsMajor       0    1
CustID   
1          [3,1]  [1]
2          [1,1]  []
```

Everything work is fine but **it is very slow**.

I find many solutions and I think I should use `bincount` (a function of NumPy), but it doesn't work:

```
df_result = (df.groupby(['CustID','IsMajor'])['MatchID']
             .agg(lambda x: np.bincount(x))
             .unstack('IsMajor',fill_value = []))
```

Can I improve performance with `bincount` or another solution?

Comment: Why are you trying to store lists as elements of a dataframe? You can get scalars, and therefore better performance with `df.groupby(['CustID','IsMajor', 'MatchID']).size()`

Comment: I updated my post. I tried with `size()`: `df.groupby(['CustID','IsMajor', 'MatchID']).size().groupby(level=[0,1]).agg(list).unstack('IsMajor')` but it is not working.

Comment: that doesn't explain why you want lists as elements in your dataframe. what are you trying to do?

Comment: in my `df_result` if I not set `list`, it doesn't work. `df.groupby(['CustID','IsMajor', 'MatchID']).size()` return wrong my expect result

Comment: what doesn't work? what are you ultimately trying to achieve? i don't understand why you want lists in your dataframe

Comment: Please come to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65911939/how-to-groupby-multiple-columns-with-count-unique-value-in-python-pandas

Comment: That does not explain _why_ you want your data in this format and what you will do with it once it is.

Comment: Because I have a function and get column `0` and column `1` is parameters with the format above.

Comment: you're not providing any meaningful context here, and it's going to be impossible to help. my advice is to rewrite that function that you're not sharing to accept a dataframe that contains scalars instead of lists or sets

Comment: I'm sorry for that, your advice is good, I will try to do it now!!